# Existing method/snippet to track files created by Console Application in c#

Tags: c#, .net, console

I was unable to find much information on this (thus no snippet). I want my console application or maybe a background task to log all the activity that is done to a certain file. If someone renames it, changes directories, makes a copy of it, etc. I would like to be able to log that data and aggregate it. If you could point me in the right direction, hint or provide a snippet I would very much appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the FileSystemWatcher class.

Here's an example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26528/C-Application-to-Watch-a-File-or-Directory-using-F